# XXXController not found you need to call Get.put or Get.lazyPut

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to create simple app with next layout:

[image]

Buttons should switch Widget1\Widget2.

I wrote next code (copy-past ready):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: HomeBinding(),
      initialRoute: '/widget1',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
              children: [
                Widget1(), 
                Widget2()
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
              onTap: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().changeTabIndex,
              items: [
                _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: CupertinoIcons.home,
                  label: 'Button1',
                ),
                _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: CupertinoIcons.rocket_fill,
                  label: 'Button2',
                ),
              ])),

      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/widget1',
          page: () => Widget1(),
          binding: Widget1_Bindings(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/widget2',
          page: () => Widget2(),
          binding: Widget2_Bindings(),
        ),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
    );
  }
}

class NavigationBarController extends GetxController {
  static NavigationBarController get to => Get.find();
  var tabIndex = 0.obs;

  void changeTabIndex(int index) {
    tabIndex.value = index;
    update();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Controller1 extends GetxController {
  var _test2 = "test1".obs;
  get test1 => this._test2.value;
}

class Controller2 extends GetxController {
  var _test2 = "test2".obs;
  get test1 => this._test2.value;
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Widget1"),
    );
  }
}


class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
     Get.lazyPut(() => NavigationBarController());
  }
  
}

class Widget1_Bindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => Controller1());
  }
}

class Widget2_Bindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => Controller2());
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Widget2"),
    );
  }
}

_bottomNavigationBarItem({required IconData icon, required String label}) {
  return BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(icon),
    label: label,
  );
}
```

Code have two problems. First one is that I am getting error:
[image]

The second one is that I can;t figure out how to get GetX routing like: `Get.to` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

First off, you have an `initialRoute` and a `home` defined in your `GetMaterialApp` and they're 2 different destinations. Use one or the other, not both.

You were binding the `NavigationBarController` to what was defined in your `initialRoute` but the app was trying to go to the `Scaffold` you have in the `home` property. So that binding was never getting called and that is the reason for the controller not found error.

Since your `NavigationBarController` is basically needed globally, and not on a page by page basis, I'd lose the binding for that and just initialize it in `main` before running the app.

```
void main() {
  Get.put(NavigationBarController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Second, if you're using an observable variable from a `GetX` class, and you're expecting a change in the UI, it needs to be wrapped in an `Obx` or `GetX` widget. So wrap your `BottomNavigationBar` in an `Obx`.

```
   bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
          onTap: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().changeTabIndex,
          items: [
            _bottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: CupertinoIcons.home,
              label: 'Button1',
            ),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: CupertinoIcons.rocket_fill,
              label: 'Button2',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Same thing with your `IndexedStack`. It needs to be wrapped in an `Obx` to rebuild on changes of the `tabIndex`.

```
Obx(
    () => IndexedStack(
    index: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
    children: [Widget1(), Widget2()],
   ),
  ),
```

Now your `BottomNavigationBar` will work. As for `bindings`, since your app is based on tabs and not navigating to full pages, you're never having to manually navigate to a page with `Get.to(() => Widget1());`, That scenario is when `Bindings` can come in handy, but for this case I don't see any benefit to using them. I would just initialize the controller in each tab. So overall it would look like this. I got rid of the `getPages` also because they're not getting used.

```
void main() {
  Get.put(NavigationBarController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(
          () => IndexedStack(
            index: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
            children: [Widget1(), Widget2()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().tabIndex.value,
          onTap: Get.find<NavigationBarController>().changeTabIndex,
          items: [
            _bottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: CupertinoIcons.home,
              label: 'Button1',
            ),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: CupertinoIcons.rocket_fill,
              label: 'Button2',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationBarController extends GetxController {
  static NavigationBarController get to => Get.find();
  var tabIndex = 0.obs;

  final widgetList = <Widget>[Widget1(), Widget2()];

  void changeTabIndex(int index) {
    tabIndex.value = index;
  //  update(); don't need this, only if you're using GetBuilder
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Controller1 extends GetxController {
  var _test2 = "test1".obs;
  get test1 => this._test2.value;
}

class Controller2 extends GetxController {
  var _test2 = "test2".obs;
  get test1 => this._test2.value;
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(Controller1());
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Obx(() => Text(controller.test1)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(Controller2());
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Obx(() => Text(controller.test1)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_bottomNavigationBarItem({required IconData icon, required String label}) {
  return BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(icon),
    label: label,
  );
}
```

Also if it were me I'd be using `GetBuilder` for everything and not observable streams, because you're not doing anything that really justifies a stream. They both work, but `GetBuilder` is the most performant option.

**UPDATE**:

To answer your question in the comment: No, you don't need an `IndexedStack`.

You could pass in a list of widgets at a given index and when the index changes the `Obx` rebuilds. The note about const constructors is not related to this but something you should do whenever you can.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _widgetList = const <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2()
  ]; // add const constructors to both these widgets

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<NavigationBarController>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(
          () => Center(
            child: _widgetList[controller.tabIndex.value], // or _widgetList.elementAt(controller.tabIndex.value)
          ),
        ),
      ),
...
```

Comment: big thanks for your answer! Could you also say when `bindings` are useful? When I am using separate screens\pages?

Comment: Yes, while not necessary, they can be handy when using regular navigation to different screens.

Comment: I have kept Get.put() in main function, but page is not loading and in terminal it is showing ```flutter: Null check operator used on a null value```but i didn't used null check operator(!)...(My issue is with BottomNabBar)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason** : It is happened when Get.find() is called before Get.put(Controller).
Calling Get.find() Before initializing the Get.put() shows the error

**Solution** : Simply you can call Get.put(controller) into your main class as belows. So then Get.find() from any class will get it.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final YourController controller = Get.put(YourController());
  ...
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return MaterialApp(
    ......
  
}
```

Note : Though there has so many ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was

```dart
Get.to(() => const OurDonorView())
```

Instead

```dart
Get.toNamed('/profile');
```